# values are automatically changed after click submit button

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have code here. There are no errors in this code, but when I was  tried to execute this, the output is shown just for a fraction of second. After that, the fields are changed to null. I want all the values to be shown, even after clicking the submit button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calcu() {
        var h = parseInt(document.getElementById("height").value);
        var w = parseInt(document.getElementById("weight").value);
        var r = h + w;
        document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = r;
        if (r < 50) {
            var x = document.getElementById("report");
            x.innerHTML = "less 50";
        }
        if (r > 50) {
            var xy = document.getElementById("report");
            xy.innerHTML = "high 50";
        }
    }
```

```
<body>
    <form onsubmit="calcu();">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Height:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="height">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Weight:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="weight">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="CALCULATE">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p id="res"></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p id="report">REPORT</p>
        <p id="tip"></p>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: Yeah... if you have pasted something... its not showing for us..

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 function calcu() {
  var h = parseInt(document.getElementById("height").value);
  var w = parseInt(document.getElementById("weight").value);
  var r = h + w;
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = r;
  if (r < 50) {
   var x = document.getElementById("report"); 
   x.innerHTML = "less 50";
  }
  if (r > 50) {
   var xy = document.getElementById("report"); 
   xy.innerHTML = "high 50";

  }
 }
</script>
</head>

Comment: <body>
<form onsubmit="calcu();">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Height:</td>
<td><input type="text" id="height"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Weight:</td>
<td><input type="text" id="weight"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="CALCULATE"></td>
<td><p id="res"></p></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p id="report">REPORT</p>
<p id="tip"></p>
</form>

Comment: @Jason i post the post

Comment: Please put it in your main posts body. In the comments is not a good idea.

Comment: PLEASE EXCUSE ME, I DON'T KNOW HOW TO POST CODE HERE. @Jason

Comment: @user3247768 You can use the 'code' button when submitting your post. It looks like `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

Show Your Code First for more.

As much i can from your statement is that you have a button which is type submit and your values are not holding because when you click on submit type button it will post your data and find the next where it has to go in action attribute as if you have not given the action attribute (a/c to me ) so its reloading the page which refreshing the whole content that's why your page is not holding the data.
But if you want it to be hold make your button type simple "Button".
I think this will resolve your problem.

Comment: <html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>BMI CALCULA</title>
</head>
<body id="stage" class="theme">
 <form onsubmit="calcu();">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>Height:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="height"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Weight:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="weight"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="CALCULATE"></td>
    <td><p id="res"></p></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <p id="report">REPORT</p>
  <p id="tip"></p>
 </form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 function calcu() {
  var h = parseInt(document.getElementById("height").value);
  var w = parseInt(document.getElementById("weight").value);
  var r = h + w;
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = r;
  if (r < 50) {
   var x = document.getElementById("report"); 
   x.innerHTML = "less 50";
  }
  if (r > 50) {
   var xy = document.getElementById("report"); 
   xy.innerHTML = "high 50";

  }
 }
</script>

Answer (score 0):

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
  <script type="text/javascript" >

      function calcu() {
          var h = parseInt(document.getElementById("height").value);
          var w = parseInt(document.getElementById("weight").value);
          var r = h + w;


          document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = r;
          if (r < 50) {
              var x = document.getElementById("report");
              x.innerHTML = "less 50";
          }
          if (r > 50) {
              var xy = document.getElementById("report");
              xy.innerHTML = "high 50";
          }
      }
  </script>
  </head>



  <body>
      <form id="form1" >
      <table>
              <tr>
            <td>Height:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="height" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Weight:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="weight"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="CALCULATE" onclick="calcu();" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <p id="res"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p id="report">REPORT</p>
    <p id="tip"></p>
</form>
```

This will do good You are calling function on form submit which reloads the page so previous page does not exist thats why is not doing any good so your have to change your button type to button and on button click you can call the function you will get your desired result.